# Split torch dataset without shuffling

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, transformer-model, pytorch-dataloader

I'm using `Pytorch` to run Transformer model. when I want to split data (tokenized data) i'm using this code:

```
train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(
                                                            tokenized_datasets,
                                                            [train_size, test_size])
```

`torch.utils.data.random_split` using shuffling method, but I don't want to shuffle. I want to split it sequentially.

Any advice? thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `random_split` method has no parameter that can help you create a non-random sequential split.

The easiest way to achieve a sequential split is by directly passing the indices for the subset you want to create:

```
# Created using indices from 0 to train_size.
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(tokenized_datasets, range(train_size))

# Created using indices from train_size to train_size + test_size.
test_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(tokenized_datasets, range(train_size, train_size + test_size))
```

Refer: [PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html).

Comment: Thank you, it working like what I want...